# Create an Android Virtual Device in Windows 7

Tags: android, emulation

I have a laptop with Windows 7 64 bit, 4GB RAM and i3 processor configuration on which I have installed Android Studio for Android application development. Now I need to run the apk on a virtual device. I have created the AVD but it will not launched -- it shows some error. I don't know whether I have made a mistake during AVD creation.

How can I create the AVD with device specification? Is there any emulator available online with a resolution change option?

Answer (score 0):

To create a device with own spec select Tools -> AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device (bottom left) -> New Hardware Profile -> Here Configure your new Device  with what properties you want such as screen resolution and RAM memory. If you want you can download custom Samsung skins from Samsung developers website but the ones in Android Studio work well. Hope this answers your question.